# React-Native Packager does not detects the file changes on windows

Tags: android, windows, reactjs, react-native

I'm using node v6.2.0 on windows 8.1
And react-native v0.28.0 with react v15.1.0 .

I was having the same problem in node 4.x too!
Updating node is also not helping.
The packager does not pick the changes or not able to detect the file changes at all. 
Tried all the options hot/live reloading but packager sends the same old bundle which was build on first request. After subsequent requests the response is the same no changes at all.

The packager takes too long for getting ready to respond.

Its frustrating for me that i have to restart the packager, unistall old app, reinstall the app using `react-native run-android` and packager as `react-native start --clear-cache`.

Also doing `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` just to be on safer side but this does not work too.

Tried running genymotion and avd also.
Its just too much for me to do this tedious work.

My whole time is being wasted on this. This makes me sad that I want to learn and develop the react-native apps but i just cant because I have windows pc that just sucks now. I don't know its the problem with my pc or packager but when i start the editor and emulator either avd or genymotion my pc just gets slower and slower.

Comment: Hi! you tried run react-native init again after node6 install?

Comment: No i haven't tried that. Will try and check if that works or not.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and found out, that in my .git-directory a file named "index.lock" was present. After i deleted this file, the refresh happened immediately and everything worked again as expected with packager after code changes.

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar problem and this have worked for me :
i've created a `metro.config.js` in  my project's root dir
then inside the file:

```
module.exports = { resolver: { useWatchman: false } };
```

and it works.
hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure **all** of the steps you mention are required to get the packager to work correctly? Although I develop with React Native on a Mac, I find that whenever I switch apps, possibly when switching between Dev <---> Production builds also, I need to close the packager before running `react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android`.

Although it seems necessary to close the packager when switching apps, I've never had to uninstall and reinstall an app on the device or simulator to get everything paying nice together.

Comment: I have tried all the step that i could find to get packager working. Seems the problem is with file watcher. Watchman is not for windows so there might be some problems with the file watcher.

Comment: Ah, it seems I may have missed the point. What you say about Watchman on Windows sounds plausable and likely. Best of luck.

Comment: Updated `react-native-cli` and reinstalled all the deps, this is also not working.This is the Packager's issue that is causing the problem. Not even a single change is detected.